# How to simplify if-statement inside web scraping code?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get info from page1,2,3... in this page https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?limit=0 (`instead of page=1, page=2 and on, it goes like limit=0,limit=50, limit=100...`). How can I simplify the code inside de IF functions?

```
data = []

def main(number):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = 'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?limit={}'

    
    if number <= 1:
        driver.get(url.format(0))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        results = soup.find_all('tr', class_= 'ranking-list')

        for result in results:
            Anime = result.find('h3', class_='hoverinfo_trigger fl-l fs14 fw-b anime_ranking_h3').text.replace('\n','')
            Date = result.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').text.replace('\n','')
            No_eps = result.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').text.replace('\n','')
            Ranking = result.find('td', class_='rank ac').text.replace('\n','')
            Score = result.find('div', class_='js-top-ranking-score-col di-ib al').text.replace('\n','')
            data.append({
                'Anime':Anime,
                'Date':Date,
                'No_eps':No_eps,
                'Ranking':Ranking,
                'Score':Score
            })
    elif number >= 2:
        for limit in range(0,(int(number)*50), 50):
            driver.get(url.format(limit))

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            results = soup.find_all('tr', class_= 'ranking-list')

            for result in results:
                Anime = result.find('h3', class_='hoverinfo_trigger fl-l fs14 fw-b anime_ranking_h3').text.replace('\n','')
                Date = result.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').text.replace('\n','')
                No_eps = result.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').text.replace('\n','')
                Ranking = result.find('td', class_='rank ac').text.replace('\n','')
                Score = result.find('div', class_='js-top-ranking-score-col di-ib al').text.replace('\n','')
                data.append({
                    'Anime':Anime,
                    'Date':Date,
                    'No_eps':No_eps,
                    'Ranking':Ranking,
                    'Score':Score
                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of guessing the possible next page number, i would try to extract the specific url / parameter from the button, if it exists:

```
if soup.select_one('a.link-blue-box.next'):
    url = 'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php'+soup.select_one('a.link-blue-box.next').get('href')
else:
    break
```

It also do not need the big gun `selenium`, simplify and use `requests` instead and to get stripped text may use `.get_text(strip=True)`.

##### Example

For purpose of demonstration the limit starts from 22100 simply set it to 0 to get all results.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?limit=22100'
data = []
while True:
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    
    for e in soup.find_all('tr', class_= 'ranking-list'):
        Anime = e.h3.get_text(strip=True),
        Date = e.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').get_text(strip=True)
        No_eps = e.find('div', class_='information di-ib mt4').get_text(strip=True)
        Ranking = e.find('td', class_='rank ac').get_text(strip=True)
        Score = e.find('div', class_='js-top-ranking-score-col di-ib al').get_text(strip=True)
        data.append({
            'Anime':Anime,
            'Date':Date,
            'No_eps':No_eps,
            'Ranking':Ranking,
            'Score':Score
        })
    if soup.select_one('a.link-blue-box.next'):
        url = 'https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php'+soup.select_one('a.link-blue-box.next').get('href')
    else:
        break
data
```

Comment: Great! It works good but how could I get the data starting from one limit until the other one, like starting from limit=0 up to limit=150 for example?